# Can robot run on mini Stirling engine?

Tags: power, power-engineering

Can I run a robo-car (with battery for electrical stuff) using [this](http://www.dx.com/p/neje-diy-mini-hot-air-stirling-engine-motor-model-toy-antique-copper-silver-grey-365004#.V8Jeplt97IU) mini Air Stirling Engine ?

Using this engine, I can never power my motors. So I am looking to run my Robot directly on this engine (altering my chassis) ? Is it possible ? Whats are things I need to keep in mind ?

Comment: You would need to know how much mechanical power it delivers, and how much torque.  You would compare that with the electrical motors you would other wise have used.  Since the manufacturer doesn't say, I don't expect the power output to be more than enough to turn itself. You would also need somekind of electrically operated clutch or transmission in order to control the robot.  Stick to electric motors.  Much simpler to control.

Comment: If you really want to use a sterling motor, get one with known power ratings.  I expect it'll cost more than 28 Eur, though.

Comment: I am actually trying to run my robot on Acetylene :). I think peltier (TEG) wont be much helpful. So I thought Stirling engine would be suitable. Can you give the link of sterling motor (28 Eu+) ? Thanks for your replay. :D

Comment: Out of curiousity, I had a look around.  The only folks I could find who actually give power ratings are selling a 5HP unit intended to provide cheap power at remote sites.  5 HP would be kind of overkill.  Aside from that, I found someone who tested his own stirling motor and found a total power output of some 10s of milliwatts.

Comment: Might be easier to find a small steam engine with enough power.

Comment: I cant find anything around me! Can you please share me the link ?

Comment: For which?  The 5 HP, or the guy who tested his stirling motor, or for a small steam engine.

Comment: For "Might be easier to find a small steam engine with enough power. – JRE "

Comment: [These guys probably can help.](http://www.crabfu.com/steamtoys/). That's bunches of steam powered R/C models.  Some of the steam engines appear to be commerially available toy steam engines.

Answer (score 1):

There was a major revision to the question as I wrote this but here goes ...

[image]

*Figure 1. The Stirling engine in question.*

That device doesn't look like it will do any useful work but let's do some calculations.

The flame looks about the same size as you might get from a tea light. These are about 10 g and last for about 5 hours. Burn rate is \$ \frac {10}{5 \times 60 \times 60} = 0.55 \mu g/s \$.

The energy density of wax is 42 kJ/g so we can calculate the power in J/s or watts: \$ P = mE = 0.55 \mu \times 42k = 23~W \$.

On the face of it this looks promising but as can be seen from the photo most of the heat is bypassing the bulb and you'd be lucky to get 10% of it heating the hot bulb. That takes us down to **2.3 W**.

The maximum efficiency of the Stirling engine is 50% [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_engine) and this unit is not optimised at all so I would guess 10% would be generous. We're down to **0.23 W**.

Now throw in some mechanical losses and you can see that we'd be down about 0.1 W or so.

Next hook up your generator and say you could get 50% efficiency in the mechanical to electrical conversion we're down to **50 mW**. At 5 V you would have enough current to light an LED.

For comparison the power output of my Shimano bicycle alternator (usually incorrectly referred to as a dynamo) is 3 W and probably costs me 5 or 6 W of extra cycling effort - probably 3 to 4%.

Links: [Measuring the energy output of a tea light](http://www.instructables.com/id/measuring-the-energy-out-put-of-a-tea-light/step6/The-MathsResults/).

Comment: Another aside is a lot of small Stirling/Flame Sucker engines I have seen are also not self starting, they need a bump start. Problematic for a robot so would be another potential design consideration if it got that far.

Comment: @D-on: Could the robot start it with a hand crank? ;^)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will you recommend Peltier module (TEG) instead of this ?

Comment: No. I'd recommend a battery. There's a reason the world is moving that way!